# Copy data from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have to copy data from several tables from SQL Server to Oracle. The tables have the same names on both DBs and the total number of rows to be copied is aboput 300 records. So some INSERT statements will be enough.
I tried using SSMS Tools. It generated me scripts with INSERT statements but the execution on Oracle fails because of the UNION clause (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found).

Can someone recommand me another easy way to copy the data.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT INTO tbl SELECT x UNION SELECT y UNION SELECT z` isn't valid Oracle not because of the UNION, but because of the `SELECT`s.

You could simply change it to `INSERT INTO tbl SELECT x FROM DUAL UNION SELECT y FROM DUAL UNION SELECT z FROM DUAL`

You could quickly do this manually with a search and replace `UNION` with `DUAL UNION` and add one `DUAL` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the Microsoft SQL Server database to Oracle, you need to create a repository to store the required repository tables and PL/SQL packages.

Have a look at this article

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

You also need to create database capture scripts as in here

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/viewlets/sqlserver_capture.swf

These are in sqlserver.ocp format

Answer (score 0):

There is a copy feature in SQL Server 4.1 - which does copy table from SQL Server to Oracle.  For no so big tables, it works fine however, for larger tables you may get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is in case of Migration of data from SQL server to Oracle.  However, the concern here is just for getting copied sql server database to Oracle.

Comment: Hmm.. Not really answering the question but rather rewordingand simplifying the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about "NOT converting" - it is just copying the sql server database objects table to oracle.  If you go to Tools Menu of the recent SQL Developer to you will see "database copy" however there is also a another feature "migration" on the same sql developer 4.1's tools menu

So Oracle SQL developer has two separate features - 1. Data Migration 2. Data copy
Look the sql developer's manual - you are talking Data Migration feature and question is all about "Copy"of table or tables data.